# Providing permission to specific user to access NFS share

Tags: linux, network-shares, nfs, export

I have two machines between which I need to share a folder.

On server1, I have the user 'appuser' that needs to access (read/write/delete) on this share.

On server2, 'root' accesses this share and writes to it.

I have the following in /etc/exports on server1:

```
/home/app-share 999.999.99.99/28(rw,insecure,sync,no_root_squash)
```

where the number is the IP address. How can I change this to allow 'appuser' access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS doesn't have share-level permissions. Access to the file on a NFS share follows normal *nix permissions.

Comment: Okay - so how do I give this useraccount permission to access this share? (sorry if i'm asking a very basic question)

Comment: It has access to the share already. You need to modify the permissions of the files and directories within the share using `chmod`, `chown`, `setfacl`, etc.

Comment: Actually no, the user account does not have access to it... could it be because its in /home/app-share? I only see that user's home directory. What's a conventional location for such a file-share folder?

Comment: Under `/srv` is generally a good place to put service data.

Comment: and that folder will be accessible to all users on the system? (i'll just have one other user - the account under which I operate the website)

Comment: whats /mnt typically used for?

Comment: Again, that is based on the *nix permissions within it.

Comment: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

Comment: Wow - thats a great reference! Thanks - will act on your advice!

Comment: Hi Ignacio - I had trouble changing ownership - I've added a separate question - http://superuser.com/questions/198206/changing-file-and-folder-ownership-from-root - please help if you can.