# Changing file and folder ownership from root?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, nfs, chown

I created a folder structure as root and now need to transfer ownership to an ordinary user.

This question is linked to this one - [Providing permission to specific user to access NFS share](https://superuser.com/questions/198191/providing-permission-to-specific-user-to-access-nfs-share)

I have a folder /srv/app-share that needs to be visible/writeable to user1

I tried (as root):

```
root@server [/]# chown -R user1:user1 /srv/
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What messages did you get, any errors? Did you try without the last slash in `/srv/` so that it specifically indicates the directory itself?

As simple test confirms it works my side, however I did not specify a group:

```
root@server [/]# chown -R user1: /srv/
```

Perhaps there is no group called 'user1' in your case? run `groups | grep user1` and see if you have that user group.

Comment: Interesting - you were right that there is no group as user1, but even using your command, as user1, I'm still not able to see/navigate to /srv

Comment: Im confused, you can't navigate to /srv? Does it not exist then? I thought you can't set the owner.

Comment: what does `ls -a /srv/` show you? I get an empty dir `. ..`

Comment: It was created by root, and the root can navigate to it. But after chown-ing it, it's not visible for user1 (/srv)

Comment: umm - just for clarification, it wasnt visible before to user1 either...

Comment: I think you are trying to set the directory owner on a machine that does not exist on that machine. Why not map the share into user1's /home, so that the share and all files fall under user1 implicitly?